# Wordpress Widget PHP output in page file

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I have created a Widget for my Wordpress theme and want to output its content.

The Widget is shown in the Backend under Widgets so this works fine.

Here is the code in my page.php file

```
<?php if ( !dynamic_sidebar('Content Footer') ) : ?>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
            <div id="contentfooter">


            </div>
        </div><!--/.col -->

    </div><!--/.row -->   
<?php endif; ?>
```

Unfortunately everything within the php tags is not shown. Just the raw content I created in the Backend Widget.

It works when I put the Condition inside the HTML Stuff:

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">

            <div id="contentfooter">

                <?php if ( !dynamic_sidebar('Content Footer') ) : ?>    
                <?php endif; ?> 

            </div>

    </div><!--/.col -->

</div><!--/.row -->
```

But then the HTML code is always shown even if I don't use the Widget on a particular page.

Here is the Widget Deklaration in my functions.php:

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
    register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => __( 'Content Footer'),
    'id' => 'content_footer',
    'description' => __( 'Content Footer Area', 'twentyeleven' ),
    'before_widget' => '',
    'after_widget' => '',
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="content-footer-header">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
));
```

Does someone know what I need to change in order to only output the code if the Widget area is used?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `is_active_sidebar()` to check if you have widgets in this sidebar and then print his content.

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar('content_footer') ) : ?>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
            <div id="contentfooter">
                <?php dynamic_sidebar('content_footer'); ?>
            </div>
        </div><!--/.col -->

    </div><!--/.row -->   
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer :)
But now it does not display the Widgets content anymore.
I edited the Widget Deklaration in the functions.php to the start post in case its helpful.

Comment: You need to check 2 things 1. if the sidebar area "Content Footer" is not empty. 2. if the sidebar "Content Footer" is register and thats his name (typos).